# Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app on heroku App

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, npm-version

I have added node_modules in .gitignore that's not issue!

How to solve this errors because in engines I have specified version of both.

[image]
Here is Code :

```
{
  "name": "server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  
  "engines": {
    "node":"12.6.2",
    "npm":"6.14.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js"
  },
  "author": "smeet_kothari",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1"
  }
}
```

and this is my index.js file [image]

And Code of index.js file.

```
const app = express();

app.get('/', (req,res) => {
    res.send({hi:'there'});
});

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(PORT);
```

```
G:\01) Web Development\10) nodejs project\[FreeCourseSite.com] Udemy - Node with React Fullstack Web Development\MailFeed\server>heroku -v
heroku/7.47.7 win32-x64 node-v12.16.2
```

*Procfile* has been added too!
[image]

Thanks for solution in advance!

Comment: and consider posting your code is much better then posting pictures of it

Comment: no @Alex i haven't pushed that one in git

Comment: Can I get your github? then I can try it on my own

Comment: the spelling of start is wrong

Comment: that to solved still cant figure it out!
```"heroku-postbuild": "npm run build"``` does this works in *scripts*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you have not defined Procfile for the project try it first if still not solved  comment the total error appearing in the command line

Comment: deleted my prev repo on heroku tried it all again from scratch added ```web: node index.js``` in Procfile but it dosent seem to work till!

Comment: git push heroku HEAD:master try this command instead of  git push heroku master
this will help may be

Comment: https://help.heroku.com/sharing/19224981-62d5-4c31-926b-ce572bd27338 tried your solution not working